# How to allow anonymous access only to the front page of a website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following settings in web config to prevent anonymous access to my website.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I would like to allow anonymous access only to the front page of my website. How do I achieve this? I am using ASP .NET MVC 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to enable anonymous access to controllers / actions you have to enable it in your Web.Config:

```
<location path="Home/Index">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

A better approach for a pure MVC app is to use the Authorize attribute and enable access to all users in the web.config.

```
public void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Home/Index");
}
```

It is working i have checked that.

Comment: This won't work. If I put the path to "Home/Index", it will allow www.foo.com/home/index, not www.foo.com.

Comment: just try with this custom attribute..http://blog.tomasjansson.com/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application

Answer (score 0):

Set your login url to your home page, like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Home/Index" />
</authentication>
```

It will redirect anonymous users to the login page.

Or you can use [AllowAnonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute in your Action (Index action in the Home controller or wherever it is)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: How is this solving my issue? I want to allow anonymous users to my front page. not redirect them to the login page.

Comment: you are replacing the login page url with your home page url, so your home page become your login page.

Comment: But I don't want my home page to be my login page. :)

Comment: Then try to use AllowAnonymous attribute in your action (Index action in Home Controller or wherever is your index action)

Comment: I am using ASP .NET MVC 3.5. I believe that's a feature in ASP .NET MVC 4.

Comment: Not trying to be rude just wondering, isn't right that if the ONLY annon access is your home, and you have a login page, then you have 2 options: 1) your home is you login or 2) your login page is useless (because auth is handled aside from your webapp) ?

Comment: lol, 2 factor authentication make my previous statement false :D